# How to resolve EXC_BAD_Acess on setToolbar: method to set NSToolbar to window?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nswindow, nstoolbar

I am trying to set NSToolBar to my window with setToolBar: method but its causing crash. As parameter to method is not nil & window to which toolbar to be set is also not nil. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some more info? Your code and the crash report would be pretty handy.

Comment: Can you please provide us with the code you are using to set the toolbar?

Comment: NSToolbar *testtoolbar = [[NSToolbar alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"test"];
    [testtoolbar setDelegate:self];
    [testtoolbar setDisplayMode:NSToolbarDisplayModeIconOnly];
    [testtoolbar setAllowsUserCustomization:YES];
    [testtoolbar setAutosavesConfiguration:YES];